# What's the difference between two params of web3.eth.filter?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python

I read official [manual](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

What the difference between this

```
web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 'pending', 'toBlock': 'latest'})
```

and this?

```
web3.eth.filter('latest')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 'pending', 'toBlock': 'latest'})

When you call get or watch on this filter, you will get event logs of events occurring between `fromBlock` and `toBlock`. Since `'latest'` is a moving pointer, you'll get event logs from future blocks too.

> web3.eth.filter('latest')

when you call watch on this filter, you will get the block hash of the latest block.